# How to pass variable into a string? Jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

How do I pass in a variable into a template in Jinja2?
I can normally do it like

```html
<p>Hello, {{ var }}</p>
```

And then in python do:

```py
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html', var = "World")
```

Which will result in:
`Hello, World`
But, let's say I want a custom bg-color for every page.

If I try

```html
<body bgcolor="{{ bg_color }}">
</body>
```

and in python do:

```py
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html', bg_color = "black")
```

It doesn't work! Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please specify *what* does not work?

Comment: The color doesn't change

Comment: If you have an html5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very beginning of your page), then this is the reason as HTML5 do not allow this attribute anymore. Rather use CSS for that: `<body style="background-color: {{ bg_color }}">`

Comment: I removed the Doctype, but it still not working. I even tried using CSS, but it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jinja2` [template inheritance](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance)

in your base template you need to add `block` like

## base.html

```
[..]

<body{% block body_attributes %}{% endblock %}>

[..]
```

and then in child templates you extend `base.html` template like:

## page1.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body_attributes %}class="bg-red"{% endblock %}

[..]
```

## page2.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body_attributes %}class="bg-blue"{% endblock %}

[..]
```

you can add other attributes (`id`, `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example3" data-offset="0"` if you are using the bootstrap scrollspy ... ) for the `body` tag depending on the page

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can bind class like that. Here is an example of conditional class binding if its useful in your case.

```
<div class="{% if black_backgroud %} black {% endif %}">...</div>
```

and in python

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html', black_backgroud = True)
```